# why get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory error?

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager, android-internet

I use DownloadManager class to download a file in android

and this is my code for download:

```
Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(urlString);
DownloadManager.Request request = new
DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
            request.setDescription(des).setTitle(titleAudio).setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED).
                        setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                                "/my file name/" , titleAudio + String.valueOf(colForUrl) + pasvand);

                long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
                prefEdit.putLong(strPref_Download_ID, id);
                prefEdit.commit();
```

but when I run app in some device(Samsung Galaxy S5) I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/emulated/0/my file name
```

and this is caused in setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(..)

but in Nexus 7 every thing is right , I have not any problem!!
So, Where is my wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html):

`setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String dirType, String subPath)`

- dirType - the directory type to pass to getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)
- subPath - the path within the external directory, including the destination filename

> dirType Should be one of DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PODCASTS,
>   DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, DIRECTORY_ALARMS, DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS,
>   DIRECTORY_PICTURES, DIRECTORY_MOVIES, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, or
>   DIRECTORY_DCIM. May not be null.

So, for example, try:

`setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, titleAudio + String.valueOf(colForUrl) + pasvand);`

And go from there if it's not exactly the folder that you want.

Comment: But in nexus 7 I run app and It`s work!! create my directory without 
any error! I think this is because public storage!
in Galaxy S5 and S4 public storage is sd card , but nexus7 don't have any sd card! what do you think?!

Comment: Yes, maybe that's part of the problem. Have you set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on your manifest?

Comment: Yes , So how I can create file in root of directory?!