# DownloadManager IllegalStateException creating a download in DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Firstly, there are a lot of questions on this subject, but none reflect my issue. I have for example read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112142/android-downloadmanager-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802707/why-get-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-directory-error).

The issue that I have, is that in an *extremely* small number of cases, my function to `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` results in the following stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.onlinetvrecorder.otrapp2.listeners.DownloadUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /mnt/sdcard/Download
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2274)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:131)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4791)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /mnt/sdcard/Download
       at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:496)
       at com.myapp.Utils.download(SourceFile:752)
       at com.myapp.Receiver.onReceive(SourceFile:20)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2267)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:131)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4791)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I am using a standard `Environment` constant to tell the `DownloadManager` where to save the file.

```
android.app.DownloadManager dm = (android.app.DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("url.to.file.ext"));
request.setMimeType("mime/type");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    Utils.setDownloadRequestVisibility(request, android.app.DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}

request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file.ext");
request.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.download));

dm.enqueue(request);
```

As previously stated, there are perhaps not even 1% of users getting this error. What could be causing it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the course of writing my question, I noticed that I had probably just solved the issue myself. I was going to write what the offending device model was, but on Crashlytics it displayed "Unknown". I clicked upon that, and the following model was revealed: `GI I9500 TMMARS`. Running Android 4.

TMMARS appears to be software from [Trend Micro](https://mars.trendmicro.com/).

> Trend Micro Mobile App Reputation Service or TMMARS is a cloud-based
>   service that automatically identifies mobile threats based on app
>   behaviors.

It is extremely likely that the system is not behaving as the App expects it to, simply because it is a threat detection environment.

Example crash report:

[image: example crash report from Crashlytics]

Comment: Hey, thanks for writing this question up and then taking the time the answer it yourself. I wish more people did that to share knowledge. Question, though: our mobile app is receiving a small number of these as well. Do you know is this is a software service that automatically runs apps on the Play Store or would it be a malicious User trying to hack the app or would be a potential client trying to test the security on the app? Thanks!

Comment: It could be all the things. It isn't really possible to tell. The model name is only an indicator, someone can spoof that if they bother to make their own firmware for testing exploits. Best thing to do is to fix issues they find or just ignore them.