# TMMARS-GCM onMessageReceived

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have my app crashes, on GCM listener onMessageReceived. I figured this out from Fabric-Crashlytics. I don't know what the app received. Following is the Exception from Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mjhram.ttaxidriver.gcm_client.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:51)
   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzt(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzk(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This issue was identified by some peoples as it is caused by TMMARS (Trend Micro MARS) Service:

- [DownloadManager IllegalStateException creating a download in DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942269/downloadmanager-illegalstateexception-creating-a-download-in-directory-downloads/34942270#34942270)
- https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/176

Both references the problem, the cause, but without details, or how they solved the issue.
Following is onMessageReceived:

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {//crah here
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            sendNotification(message);
        }
}
```

The exception is raised on line [**if (from.startsWith("/topics/"))**]. I am not sure if "from" is passed as null here!

Anyone can help me figure out what is happening? and what is my apk receives?

***Note:*** This happens on Rooted device.

UPDATE#1: Receiver in *Android Manifest*

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.mjhram.ttaxidriver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you configured receiver in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, (Update#1 includes the "receiver" part in AndroidManifest.xml)