# NullPointerException on FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does anyone knows about this crash?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

It doesn't happen that much, about 0.1% of sessions.

Reported environments: GI-I9500_TMMARS / Android 4.1.1.

Comment: Have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is [discussed as an issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/16) for the Quick Start project.  Comments there from the Firebase support team indicate the problem is fixed in SDK version 9.4.0.  Are you building with that version?

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I use version 9.4.0. I will update if there's any updates on that threads.

Comment: I am also on 9.4.0 and still get this issue.

Comment: I am on 9.4.0 but faced this problem on exactly same device reported in the question: GI-I9500_TMMARS (Android 4.1.1)

Comment: @rpattabi i confirm same observation in one of my apps

Comment: The latest conversation on that thread (and my own observation) indicates that 1) the bug is still present on version 9.6.1 and 2) this crash does not come from a real user in most cases (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34942270/4834154).

Comment: See my comment below to fix the solution on every version.

Comment: I am also getting this in device GI-I9500_TMMARS (4.1.1). I am using 10.0.1

Comment: I can also confirm this issue in version 9.6.1 through a Crashlytics report. The device model is a "Batmobile - Defy Mini". Have not tested any newer version yet, since I don't know how to reproduce this. Up to know, only happend once in the last 2-3 months

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use wrong key to get value

```
Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
String name;
name = data.get("naem").toString());
//while correct key is name not naem
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to fix this error you should update firebase in your Gradle file and add the 2nd line:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1' 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' // also need to add this line.
```

Getting a "**Could not find**" error? **Make sure you have
   the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager**

Don't forget to update the Gradle file in the root folder of your project as well otherwise you won't be able to get the version **10.0.1**:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

source:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/185
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: This issue is still there , device  
GI-I9500_TMMARS , 4.1.1