# Is Batmobile Defy Mini a fake device?

Tags: twitter-fabric

Fabric reports rare crashes which I generally cannot reproduce

Fabric identifies it as Batmobile (manufacturer) Defy Mini (device model) running Android 5.0.2 
Motorola has a device named Defy Mini which was introduced in 2012 running Android 2.3.

Other answers report a fake device used to scan for viruses by Trend Micro
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34942270/923557

Here is a report of an unreproducible error involving this specific device: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/5KQ2SxazCjg

Can I ignore all crashes where this device is the only affected device?

Comment: This device is used by google play to review your app along with trend micro

Comment: https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_defy_mini_xt320-4375.php

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Can you back that up with a source? I find it weird that they would be testing apps on a device that would couldn't be Google endorsed. The phone has a arm v5 CPU yet it's running Android 4-5. Even Android 4.0 officially required arm v7 CPU. It crashes because I don't include arm v5 .so libraries with my app.

Comment: We are also facing this problem and couldn't do anything about it. You have to ignore it

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I received the same user from Sentry. I think you can ignore it. Probably it is a bot scanning your app.

Comment: Yes I saw this too in Fabric, interesting to know that there is a mobile by this name (https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_defy_mini_xt320-4375.php)

Comment: happens to our apps to, direct after pushing an update to the store it happens, cant reproduce the issues it "finds" either.

Comment: Same as @SjoerdvGestel. Every time we make a new release we get these crashes.

Comment: This device is used by google play to review your app.